# Auto setting xdebug.remote_host ip address with vagrant/puppet

Tags: php, xdebug, vagrant, puppet

I'm in the process of setting up a Vagrant environment using puppet for provisioning.

I'm stuck with one issue, I would like xdebug to 'just work' when running `vagrant up` however I need to specify the host machines ip address in the php.ini file `xdebug.remote_host`, obviously this is going to be different on each machine the config is used so I would like a way to automatically update that value when issuing `vagrant up`.

**VagrantFile:**

```
config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 9000, host: 9000
```

**.ini settings:**

```
'xdebug.default_enable=1',
'xdebug.remote_enable=1',
'xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp',
'xdebug.remote_host=localhost:9000',
'xdebug.remote_port=9000',
'xdebug.remote_autostart=0',
'xdebug.max_nesting_level=250'
```

I have also tried it with `xdebug.remote_host=localhost`

**ifconfig** results from the vagrant machine:

```
vagrant@precise64 ~ : ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0c:29:cf:f9:89
      inet addr:192.168.61.142  Bcast:192.168.61.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
```

**phpinfo()**

`REMOTE_ADDR 192.168.61.2`

`REMOTE_PORT   51886`

Just to confirm, if I give `remote_host` my actual ip address I have on my osx host machine, it works correctly.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19917148/tell-vagrant-the-ip-of-the-host-machine

Answer (score 11):

As mentioned in http://www.xdebug.org/docs/all_settings, you can set option

```
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1
```

So, xdebug will connect back to the host, which requested for web-page, and will ignore option "remote_host".

This solution has one problem: If you enable xdebug for any request, and user, opening web-page doesn't have running xdebug client (waiting for connection from server), and has non-closed `9000` port, the server **would wait for a long time** (trying to connect to client's xdebug session), before it can finally load page.
I had this problem with windows 7 machines, because it's firewall doesn't actually closes port, and connecting software can't understand, that nobody is listening port.

If this doesn't work:

I had the same situation, then I was need for VirtualBox VM with configuration, that should work on any machine with any IP.
So, I made it this way:

1. I've created virtual network interface in VirtualBox (I don't know, are there any options for this in vagrant, but it should be), and set it local address to `192.168.100.1`,
   so, my REAL machine have two addresses: `eth0:192.168.1.2`, and `vboxnet0:192.168.100.1`.
2. I've configured virtual machine with following values: `IP=192.168.100.100`, Default gateway = `192.168.100.1`
3. Configure my XDebug to `remote_ip=192.168.100.1`

And now, I have 3 copies of this machine (my copy, and 2 copies used by my co-workers), and it works fine!

So, solution is to set your IP address to some "constant one", just virtually.

Comment: I did try that but it didn't work. I took a look at the remote_host super global and the i.p was of the vagrant guest machine that PHP was running on, not my host machine.

Comment: Ok, then you should try this: 1) Configure your xdebug to use localhost:9000, so it will connect to a virtual machine' port, and 2) then forward that port to your real machine

Comment: Still no luck. Updated the question with my config.

Comment: I noticed that the REMOTE_ADDR on from phpinfo is `192.168.61.2` yet in OSX (host machine) the vmnet ip's from ifconfig are `192.168.213.1, 192.168.56.1, 192.168.61.2`

Comment: Updated answer with new info

Answer (score 0):

In case of a custom vagrant machine running GNU/Linux or using a docker image you can find the ip via the following command:

```
netstat -rn | grep "^0.0.0.0 " | cut -d " " -f10
```

To get the ip, tun this command **after** you run first:

```
vagrant ssh #login into the machine
```

## BONUS INFO in case you are or wanna run docker inside vagrant

Also an intriguing case is the one that you run php inside a docker container that is spawned inside a vagrant GNU/Linux image. In that case, do not attempt to shawn a shell of a running php image and the run the command above, find the ip that the **VM** connects back into the host, via running the command:

```
netstat -rn | grep "^0.0.0.0 " | cut -d " " -f10
```

In the running **VM**'s shell and **NOT** on a running docker container (either using `docker exec` or `docker-compose exec`). In case of an entrypoint script set an enviromental variable for the XDEBUG ip and autoset the value in case that this one is empty then autoset the ip.