# Tell Vagrant the ip of the host machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, vagrant

I am using a vagrant box as a development machine for a project with an odd dependency I can only seem to install on ubuntu.

I created my database and have my app code on my host computer, and I share them with the vagrant instance through the NFS file share and postgres config.

My issue is that, as I move my computer from work to home, the ip for my computer changes and my `database.yml` becomes invalid. To get my server and console working, I need to update the yaml file with the host's new ip address each time I join a new network.

Since the rails app is running on vagrant (even though it's files are located on my host machine), any attempt for me to grep the ip out of ifconfig will fail because it's looking at the VM and not the host box. So something like this doesn't work:

```
# database.yml
development:
  host: <%= `ifconfig en0 | grep "inet " | cut -d" " -f2` %>
```

Is there a config in the Vagrant file to pass this info through, or a way to create an ENV variable of the host ip that the ubuntu instance can read?

Comment: Do you want it to happen automatically or on Vagrant up/provision etc. ?

Comment: Automatically would be great, as I don't always shut down my instances each time I move. Just close the laptop and move.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

According to [this](https://superuser.com/a/310745/157900), you can reach the host through the VM's default gateway.

Running `netstat -rn` on the guest should give you the relevant info, on my machine changing your code above to the following looks like it would get things going for you:

```
# database.yml
development:
  host: <%= `netstat -rn | grep "^0.0.0.0 " | cut -d " " -f10` %>
```

Comment: In provision file, this can be assigned to the variable, e.g.: `GW=$(netstat -rn | grep "^0.0.0.0 " | cut -d " " -f10)`.

Comment: Alternative using awk: `GW=$(netstat -rn | awk '/^0\.0\.0\.0/ { print $2}')`

Answer (score 62):

Not sure, if it will work for everybody, though all my virtual box machines see host machine by this "magic" ip:

```
10.0.2.2
```

Don't know if it's always static, though for me works and it's very convenient - I can use laptop at home, from office - having assigned different IPs to me by routers, but my VMs know the "trusty name" of their master

Comment: Same here. How did you find this out?

Answer (score 7):

As an alternative to Matt's solution, you can also use [private networks](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/networking/private_network.html) your *Vagrantfile*.

If you add a line such as:

```
config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.42.10"
```

Vagrant will add a second adapter to the virtual machine and hook it up to host-only adapter on that subnet.

This way you can then let `database.yml` simply point to `192.168.42.1` all the time (in this example).