# Get Host IP in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a line in my Dockerfile:

```
&& echo "xdebug.remote_host=192.168.0.216" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini`
```

I want to make the IP dynamic. How would I get the host IP in there?

Comment: What do you mean by "host IP"? Are you looking for the docker host IP? or just a way to inject any IP at container run time? at container build time?

Comment: @Matt The IP address of the computer that Docker is being ran on

Answer (score 5):

You need to use [build-time variables](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#set-build-time-variables-build-arg) (–build-arg).

This flag allows you to pass the build-time variables that are accessed like regular environment variables in the RUN instruction of the Dockerfile.

So, `Dockerfile` is modified to:

```
ARG IP_ADDRESS
RUN ... && echo "xdebug.remote_host=$IP_ADDRESS" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini`
```

And you just need to define build-time variable `IP_ADDRESS` during image building:

```
$ docker build --build-arg IP_ADDRESS=<IP_ADDRESS> .
```

If you use `docker-compose`:

**1.** Create file `.env` with the following content:

```
IP_ADDRESS="<IP_ADDRESS>"
```

You can make it every time like (example is for a linux machine):

```
IP_ADDRESS=$(ip a | grep <interface> | grep inet | awk '{print $2}' | awk -F'/' '{print $1}')
echo "IP_ADDRESS=$IP_ADDRESS" > .env
```

**2.** Use the following `docker-compose.yaml` to build your image:

```
version: '3'
services:
  myservice:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        IP_ADDRESS: ${IP_ADDRESS}
```

**3.** Build the above image:

```
docker-compose build
```

Comment: Righto. Perhaps I should have been more specific. I am using Docker Compose to run the container

Comment: @Wildcard27 added information how to achieve your goal with a `docker-compose`

Comment: So I can't get this working with your method. The arguments just aren't getting set. I had to guess what you have before `IP_ADDRESS=` and `echo` as they are not Dockerfile commands. Are you able to elaborate please?

Comment: I showed you an example how to get host's IP and insert it into `.env` file. After that the value `IP_ADDRESS` will be injected to docker image building  process. The only thing that you need to change ` <interface>` with the host's interface like `em1`. You can fully avoid that. If you know the IP address of a host, you can put it into .env file, for example: `echo "IP_ADDRESS=192.168.1.2" > .env`

Comment: Right. I assumed that you meant to put the `echo` into the Dockerfile as you didn't state where those 2 lines should go. So where should they go?

Comment: They should go in your terminal before `docker-compose build` command.

Answer (score 2):

There's no simple in built way to get the Docker host IP (unless you are using Docker for Mac)

#### Entrypoint

It's best not to set a Docker host IP at build time, otherwise the image will be tied to the host it was built on and won't work anywhere else.

An `ENTRYPOINT` can be used to do the config setup based on an environment variable and then pass through all commands to the container:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ -n "$IP_ADDRESS" ]; then
  echo "xdebug.remote_host=$IP_ADDRESS" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini
else
  echo "No environment variable IP_ADDRESS set for xdebug"
fi
exec "$@"
```

Then run with:

```
docker run -e IP_ADDRESS=192.168.51.5 me/app-debug
```

#### Docker for Mac

On Docker for Mac 17.12+ you can use the host name `docker.for.mac.host.internal`

#### Xdebug

Another option is setting [`xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1` so you don't need a specific `remote_host`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18374364/1318694) for xdebug.

#### Build

Nicolay's [answer covers the build time setup](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48921238/1318694).